# Need word for "remove duplicates and keep unique instances"

Tags: word-choice, american-english

Here is a sentence.

Combine all Points and keep unique Points.

For example:

Points->  1,1,1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,5,5

**Remove duplication and keep uniqueness**

Unique Points->  1,2,3,4,5

I  need a word to express "remove duplicate Points and keep the unique Points".

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. Can you write an example sentence where the word would be used? The following is the strict rule of this community. *Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered*. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: I’m afraid you’ll need to provide a lot more context and provide an explanation of what you intend to mean using other words if you want a meaningful answer.  As it stands this question is likely to be closed as “unclear what you’re asking”

Comment: Thanks @Rathony for helping. Please check now if my question is ok.

Comment: Please do not close this question, I am new in writing question here. so please need your guidelines and suggestion. thanks

Comment: This sounds like a programming question, in which case you probably want `unique` (sometimes abbreviated `uniq`), or `nub`.

Comment: I think the word you're looking for is `dedupe`.
Looking for it also brought me here. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

*Distinct*, is it the word you are after?

Comment: @Abc If adjectives work for you, try "unique" and search for its synonyms.

Comment: _Distinct_ isn't a verb though.

Answer (score 4):

I use "***uniquify***", meaning "to prune a collection so that all instances are unique", in my job as a software engineer.

It's not the most attractive word but it fits perfectly, and most people would instantly guess what it means on first hearing.

In fact, this appears to be "a thing" already:

http://www.yourdictionary.com/uniquify

```
(third-person singular simple present uniquifies, present participle uniquifying, simple past and past participle uniquified)

(rare, slang, computing) To eliminate duplicates from a list, especially when using the *nix command/function uniq.
(rare, slang, computing) To turn an instance of a type into an instance of a new unique copy of the original type.
```

I've also seen it spelled "uniqify" (without the u after the q), and in fact that's how I would normally spell it.

EDIT:  I just realised that the reason i would write "uniqify" with no q is that the command to do this is called "uniq" (not "unique").

Comment: I can confirm that _uniquify_ is a pretty common word in the world of computing. I posted the same answer, by the way, but Max beat me by 4 minutes, so I deleted mine.